# How to use custom button instead of jquery ui buttons?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-dialog

How to implement the custom image instead of jquery dialog buttons ? There is standard buttons are there but i have designed new buttons using photoshop with extesion of .png. So i would like to use .png button instead of jquery dialog button.

I hope there is options through css , but if you give me small example, it will be very help to me.

```
jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog ({ 
 autoOpen: false,
  height: 600,
  width: 700,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false, 
  buttons : {
    "Search" : function() { // dialog button need to be customize.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GnpQ8/2/

Create a custom close button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-model").dialog({
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css({'background':'none','border':'none'});
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").html('<a href="#" role="button"><span class="myCloseIcon">close</span></a>');
            $("#dialog-model").css({ 'font-family': 'Helvetica', 'padding': '0', 'font-size': '12px' });
        },
        width: 250,
        height: 150,       
        modal: true,
        resizable: false
    });

    $("span.myCloseIcon").click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-model" ).dialog( "close" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below code from your page  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/28/)

```
   <script src="js/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.button.js">
   <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit], a,button" )
    .button()       
                });
   </script>
```

and then use your customized button like normal css

Comment: I'm using jquery button like buttons : { "search" : function() { }..updated in question section.

Comment: u mean popup window button

Comment: <input value="Hello" type="button" id="popup" class="classname"> put your css class name here

Comment: Like that u can add your image .classname {
    border: none;
    background: url('/forms/demo.png') no-repeat top left;
    padding: 2px 8px;
}

Comment: No buddy , I asking with in dialog box there is search button - this need to be customize.not open dialog link.

Answer (score 0):

.button-class {
Background; url('yourimage.png');

}

Comment: I have 4 buttons inside jquery dialog , so this button class going to be reflect which button ? how to specify the each button ?